# Signing messages as a Gnosis Safe (eip1271 support)

Tags: solidity, signature, gnosis-safe, multisignature, gnosis

Does Gnosis Safe have a native way to validate it's *own* eip1271 signatures? I know that Gnosis Safe's can have contract accounts as owners and it will verify those signatures according to eip1271 but what if I want my Gnosis Safe to sign a message that will be verified by another contract?

Let's say that my Gnosis Safe wants to submit a limit order on an exchange like 0x that uses signed messages. Assuming that 0x checks contract signatures with eip1271 how would I mark that signature as valid in my Gnosis Safe? Would I have to add a module (or something similar) to enable that functionality?

Answer (score 6):

This functionality is provided via the [CompatibilityFallbackHandler](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/handler/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.sol). This should be enabled by default on all Safes created via the Gnosis Safe web interface.

In general the Safe currently has 2 ways for such signatures:

- Approve the message on-chain via the [SignMessage library](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/SignMessageLib.sol). In this flow a Safe transaction is triggered. This is supported via the WalletConnect SafeApp.
- Collect signatures of the owners to create a composite signature that can be verified against the Safe owners and threshold. This would not require any on chain transaction, but is currently not supported by the web interface. And example for this can be found in the [tests](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/test/handlers/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.spec.ts#L86-L94)