# Can a community with a Gnosis Safe multisig sign into an app or sign a message?

Tags: gnosis-safe

The experience I’m to create is where an organization is logged in or signs an attestation message instead of an individual user. The result would be something like, “BanklessDAO is logged in”, or “BanklessDAO has signed this attestation supporting our project”. Is this possible?

Comment: This question may help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/122635/signing-messages-as-a-gnosis-safe-eip1271-support.

Answer (score 0):

No, because Gnosis safe multisig is a Smart Contract Wallet not an EOA . SCW cant sign messages like we normally do on metamask or other wallet